# LibGdx when and how should I dispose assets using an AssetManager?

Tags: libgdx

Say I have a method that loads all my assets for a Screen, this method is called in that Screens constructor:

```
public void load(){
    manager.load(pd_bg, Texture.class, textureParams);
}
```

Now when I exit that Screen, I have e method that unloads all these assets:

```
public void unLoad(){
    manager.unload(pd_bg);
}
```

Inside my Screen I might use this asset for a Sprite, like so:

```
Sprite bg = new Sprite(GdxAssetManager.manager.get(GdxAssetManager.pd_bg, Texture.class));
```

**Finally**, do I need to dispose of the texture used in this sprite even though I call the unLoad() method? i.e:

```
public void dispose(){
    GdxAssetManager.unLoad();
    bg.getTexture.dispose(); //Is this line needed?
}
```

I am also wondering, if I load all resources when I start the app, should I then unload resources when I exit a Screen? How will they be loaded up next time then (since I only load the on launch)?. 
I am using a Sprite as an example, but I guess the answer will be true for any asset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't have to (and must not) dispose it when you unload it. In general, the rule of thumb goes: *if you create it, you destroy it*. So if you create a Texture (by using the `new` keyword) then you *own* that texture and are responsible for destroying it (calling its `dispose` method). In the case of `AssetManager`, it is the `AssetManager` who owns the resource and is responsible for destroying it.

To keep track of which resources needs to be *created* and *destroyed*, `AssetManager` uses reference counting. So it is important that you eventually call `unload` for everytime you call `load`.

And because you created the `AssetManager` using the `new` keyword, you own it and you are responsible for calling its `dispose` method:

```
public class MyGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    public AssetManager assetManager;

    @Override public void create() {
        assetManager = new AssetManager();
        ...
    }
    ...
    @Override public void create() {
        assetManager.dispose();
        assetManager = null;
        ...
    }
}
```

Have a look at the documentation: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets

Btw, in your code it looks like you are using a `static` AssetManager. Although not related to your question, be aware that will lead to issues. So I'd advice you to implement a proper object oriented design instead of making things `static`.

As for your second question, it is unclear what you mean. If you mean when you should call `AssetManager#unload`, then the answer is whenever the class that called the corresponding `AssetManager#load` method no longer needs it.

For example, if you have an asset named "image.png" and you call the `assetManager.load("image.png", Texture.class)` in both your `MyGame` and `MyScreen` classes then you should call `assetManager.unload("image.png")` also in both your `MyGame` and `MyScreen` class.

Comment: Great answer, feel like I understand it know, thank you! Also, I found out about the static thing late in development and I'm planning to fix it before release :)

Comment: Followup question about static AssetManager. Is it just the `public static final AssetManager manager = new AssetManager()` that should be changed? i.e Creating normal get/set method for manager for use. Or should I remove everything that is static from my AssetManager class? i.e file-names, load-methods, etc.

Comment: Static (primitive) fields like `public final static String ASSETNAME = "asset.png"` are okay. For everything else `static` should be removed. Instead e.g. pass your game instance to the screen etc.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I already do that for everything else, just the AssetManager that is static.

Comment: @Xoppa why are you disposing `assetManager` in `create()` method ? and why are you assigning `null` after `dispose()` call  ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last two questions:
In your **launcher** class, you should load every texture you need from all screens.
Then in your screens you aceess the images you need and **you dont unload them and you also don't dispose them nor do you dispose the assetmanager.**

Then in your **launcher class** in the

```
dispose(){}
```

method you first unload evereything and then call

```
assetmanager.dispose();
```